# Can't get wifi info on Android 13

Tags: android, react-native, wifi

As title, I cant get Wifi info on android 13, it run nomally on android 12

```
    import {NetworkInfo} from 'react-native-network-info';

    NetworkInfo.getSSID().then(ssid => {
      setWifiSSID(ssid || '');

      console.log(ssid); 
      // 12: AndroidWifi
      // 13: <unknown ssid>
    });
```

**@react-native-community/netinfo** has the same issue. Has anyone to know the ways to fix it?

```
    import NetInfo from '@react-native-community/netinfo';

    NetInfo.fetch('wifi').then(state => {
      setWifiType(state.type);

      console.log(state);
    })
```

Log **Android 12**

> {   "details": {
> "bssid": "00:13:10:85:fe:01",
> "frequency": 2447,
> "ipAddress": "****",
> "isConnectionExpensive": false,
> "linkSpeed": 1,
> "rxLinkSpeed": 2,
> "ssid": "AndroidWifi",
> "strength": 99,
> "subnet": "255.255.255.0",
> "txLinkSpeed": 1   },   "isConnected": true,   "isInternetReachable": true,   "isWifiEnabled": true,   "type": "wifi"
> }

Log **Android 13**

> {   "details": {
> "bssid": "02:00:00:00:00:00",
> "frequency": 5300,
> "ipAddress": "*****",
> "isConnectionExpensive": false,
> "linkSpeed": 300,
> "rxLinkSpeed": 300,
> "strength": 99,
> "subnet": "255.255.255.0",
> "txLinkSpeed": 300   },   "isConnected": true,   "isInternetReachable": true,   "isWifiEnabled": true,   "type": "wifi"
> }

Answer (score 0):

The ssid info represents location info.

So to get them you should apply for LOCATION permission first.

Comment: Yes, I know. And as I said, "it runs normally on Android 12" means that I have requested location permission and got wifi information on Android 12 devices, but I can't get it on Android 13 devices with the same.

Comment: location with react native maps runs well on android 13